# Greatest Common Divisor of $2$ Numbers in The Integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How do I find the numbers *s* and *t* in The Integers ${\mathbb Z}$

such that:

$$21s + 8t = {\rm gcd}(21,8) $$

Comment: You could try solving the congruence $$21s \equiv 1 \pmod 8$$

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what the extended Euclidean algorithm says? It basically does exactly what you want it to. (For further information you can look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm - I am not usually a fan of wikipedia articles, but this one seems to be fairly accurate.)

Otherwise, you can go about it simply taking a couple notes while calculating the $GCD$:

$GCD(21,8)=GCD((21-3\cdot 8),8)=GCD(3,8)$.

Note: $3=3\cdot 8-21$.

$GCD(3,8)=GCD(3\cdot 3-8,8)=GCD(1,8)=1$.

We have $3\cdot 3-8=1$, and since $3= 3\cdot 8-21$ this leads to $3\cdot(3\cdot 8-21)-8=1$

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful